# How to sum views field value

Tags: 8, views

A have Drupal 8 and a custom module, which adds a custom field to a view.
I want to sum two fields in each views row.

In my module I sum two field values:

```
  public function render(ResultRow $values) {

  $value = $this->view->field['field_one']->original_value;
  $value_two = $this->view->field['field_two']->original_value;
  $sum = $value + $value_two;
  return $sum;

}
```

but I get a number 2 as a result for all rows instead of real sum. Looks like a count, not a sum.

Why so that?

Comment: What type of data is `$value` and `$value_two`?

Comment: Your function takes in a ResultRow parameter, but doesn't use it. You're getting the same value in every case because you're always calculating the sum from the same two values: `$this->view->field['field_one']->original_value` and `$this->view->field['field_two']->original_value`